# Spring Boot Repository how to cache X Entities until saving to Database

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, caching

I am currently implementing a Database based Logger for my SpringBoot Application. Since there can be hundreds of Logs in a short period of time, I'm looking for a method to store a specific Amount of Logs before they get saved in the Database.

I tried to override the save() Method of a custom Repository like someone told in a different Article but I ended up with bean errors and it didn't do what it should have done at all. I also tried to implement it directly in my Logger but since the PrimaryKey ID is only set after using the Repository.save() method my Logs where mixed up afterwards.

Comment: hey Kreuzzes, what exactly do you need to log? I just wanted to mention that the databases produce and write their own log messages. In spring and hibernate it is also possible to log the produced and executed sql-queries.

Comment: @EiriniGraonidou I'm logging various Debug Messages and info Messages created by Components, Services, Schedulers etc. of my Program. Also Exceptions get logged. Database Updates aren't logged its something custom

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [JPA callbacks for the different lifecycle events](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/apidocs/) `(PrePersist, PostPersist, etc...)`

Assuming you have implemented an entity and repository for managing books, you could define a service that utilizes the above mentioned events.

your entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(BookLoggingService.class)
class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Long id;

private String title;

private String isbn;

public Book() {}

public Book(String title, String isbn) {
    this.title = title;
    this.isbn = isbn;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getIsbn() {
    return isbn;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Book [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", isbn=" + isbn + "]";
}
}
```

Your repository:

```
interface BookRepository extends CrudRepository<Book, Long> {

}
```

your logging logic:

```
class BookLoggingService {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(BookLoggingService.class);

@PrePersist
void actOnPrePersist(Book book) {
    // implement your logging
    log.info("on pre persist of book: " + book);
}

@PostPersist
void actOnPostPersist(Book book) {
    // implement your logging logic
    log.info("the after persist: " + book.toString());
}

@PreRemove
void actOnPreRemove(Book book) {
    // implement your logging logic
    log.info("the before removed: " + book.toString());
}

@PostRemove
void actOnPostRemove(Book book) {
    // implement your logging logic
    log.info("the after removed: " + book.toString());
}
```

}

Then you could see something like:
[image]